# Identify of Currently Inserting Row

Tags: sql-server, insert, identity, identity-column

I'm working on a project and the question came up: Can an insert statement insert it's own identity in to another field?

The idea is that there would be a hierarchical arrangement of records and that the 'parent' field would point to the ID of the parent record and that the 'top' record for a given tree would just point to itself.

We could of course just leave it null for the parent or come back and insert its ID later. But I was wondering if there was any SQL Server operation to insert an IDENTITY in to another field as the record is being inserted?

EDIT: Or is there a way to specify the default value for a field to be the value of another field? That would also address the issue.

EDIT: The default field being another field has already been answered it seems, and the answer is no, use a trigger. Of course, that doesn't help the issue of constraints and non-null fields. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/661d3dc8-b053-47b9-be74-302ffa11bf76)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For this kind of hierarchy unless you are inserting explicit `ID` values with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` you would need to insert the top level first and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or the `OUTPUT` clause to get the inserted `ID` s to use for the next level down.

Answer (score 0):

To a certain degree you can. Insert allows for [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause and the OUTPUT can be redirected INTO a table which can be the same table as the one you're currently inserting into. The following example inserts a parent node but it also automatically inserts a child node which has the parent_id set to the newly generated ID during insert:

```
create table hierarchy (
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, 
    parent_id int null, 
    somefield varchar(100));


insert into hierarchy (parent_id, somefield)
    output inserted.id, 'child'
    into hierarchy (parent_id, somefield)
values (null, 'parent');    

select * from hierarchy;
```

I don't see any practical use in the end though, this is more of a show hat-trick.

Comment: That is very useful to know, but I'm looking to insert a single record with the ID in another field in addition to the ID field. The reason for this would be only in cases where the record was the parent record and so it would specify itself as the parent instead of some other pre-existing record.